# Open a file dialog when clicked using jQuery , but not support in safari

Tags: jquery, html

I use below code :-

```
$(".putimage").click(function(){
    $('#pro_image1').click();
});

<input type="file" id="pro_image1" name="pro_image1" style="display: none"/>

<input type="button" value="Parcourir" id="putimage1" class="putimage" />
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I just created a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dRD37/ and it works just fine in Safari 6.1 on OS X 10.7.

Comment: Confirmed this affects Safari 5.1.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are making a personalized upload button?

Don't hide the `input` button using `display:none`

instead do this to hide the `input` button:

`position:fixed; left:-1000px;`

I think I had the same problem before with safari. jQuery `click()` will not work on an file input that is hidden using `display:none`

This method is cross-browser (even mobile browsers).

Comment: This fixed worked great; thank you. Also note that this is not a jQuery problem, it's a problem (design flaw maybe) with Safari 5.1.

Comment: @Seth safari for windows is no longer being supported by apple. if you have the latest version of safari (i think its 7 not sure) you will see that this fix is no longer needed along with all the other bugs that safari v5 has. If you want to make your site compatible with safari I would suggest getting the latest version of safari. cheers!

Comment: Thank you @Deadpool, but I was able to reproduce this defect on Mac OS X today using Safari 5.1. One of my users discovered it. Sure, it's old, but that fix is too easy not for me to deploy it.